# Javascript - Convert large object literal into another object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, loops

I am trying to convert a Javascript object literal into another. I think it is possible with some loops, but i couldn't get it done. The target structure is shown below, "convertedData".

Fiddle can be found here: http://jsbin.com/ajemih/9/edit

Here's the JSON data:

```
var data =

{
"29-10-2012": {
    "1a": {
            "allMovement": "1",
            "allLoad": "2",
            "loadMovement": "3"
    },
        "1b": {
            "allMovement": 4,
            "allLoad": 5,
            "loadMovement": 6
    }
},
    "22-02-2013": {
    "1a": {
            "allMovement": "7",
            "allLoad": "8",
            "loadMovement": "9"
    },
        "1b": {
            "allMovement": "10",
            "allLoad": "11",
            "loadMovement": "12"
    }
}
};

for (day in data) {

    for (id in data[day]) {

        document.write(data[day][id].allMovement+"<br>");
        document.write(data[day][id].allLoad+"<br>");
        document.write(data[day][id].loadMovement+"<br>");

    }
}

/*

convertedData = [[1,7],
             [2, 8],
             [3, 9],
             ["4","10"],
             ["5","11"],
             ["6", "12"]];


convertedData = [["1a-allMovement-29-10-2012","1a-allMovement-22-02-2013],
                 ["1a-allLoad-29-10-2012", "1a-allLoad22-02-2013"],
                 ["1a-loadMovement-29-10-2012", "1a-loadMovement-22-02-2013"],
                 ["1b-allMovement-29-10-2012","1a-allMovement-22-02-2013"],
                 ["1b-allLoad-29-10-2012","1b-allLoad22-02-2013"],
                 ["1b-loadMovement-29-10-2012", "1b-loadMovement-22-02-2013"]];

*/
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle doesn't load for me. Also, yes you need a loop, probably 3.

Comment: Lol,  I had something like this as an interview question awhile back. Is there a set depth or is the depth theoretically infinite? Will take several loop or recursion

Comment: The depth is like in the example and not theoretically infinite.

Comment: Even i can't create and save a jsfiddle to show you the problem, it doesn't load at the moment. I don't know why.

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON Object.  There are only JSON _strings_.  What you have is a _JavaScript Object literal_.

Comment: Thanks, have updated it, have actualized the fiddle also!

Comment: Update: Set bounty for this question.

Comment: @MichaelMeier I am little confused... which is the converted value here.. the one with numbers or `1a-allMovement-29-10-2012`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses the jQuery.each() function:

```
var convertedObj = {};
$.each(data, function(i0,val0) {
    $.each(val0, function(i1,val1) {
        $.each(val1, function(i2,val2) {
            if (!convertedObj[i1+"-"+i2]) convertedObj[i1+"-"+i2] = [];
            convertedObj[i1+"-"+i2].push(val2);            
        });
    });
});
var convertedData = [];
$.each(convertedObj, function(i,val) {
    convertedData.push(val);
});
```

Here's the [**link to a jsbin fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/oxivec/11/edit)

(see the results in the console)

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this, tweak it as you need:

```
var out = [],
    dateKey, idx, item, itemKey, inner;

for (dateKey in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(dateKey)) {
        idx = out.length;
        out[idx] = [];
        item = data[dateKey];
        for (itemKey in item) {
            if (item.hasOwnProperty(itemKey)) {
                inner = item[itemKey];
                out[idx].push(itemKey + '-' + inner.allMovement + '-' + inner.allLoad + '-' + inner.loadMovement);
            }
        } 
    }
}
console.log(out);
```

Comment: Upvote. That goes in the right direction, but it delivers not exactly what i want.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle massiveley, please have a look! That's the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

Using underscore.js:

```
var memo = {};

_.each(data, function (elem) { 
  _.each(elem, function (elem2, idx) {
    _.each (elem2, function(elem3, idx2) {
      if (typeof memo[idx + idx2] === 'undefined')
          memo[idx + idx2] = [];
      memo[idx + idx2].push(elem3);
    });
  });
});

memo = _.map(memo, function(e) { return e; });

// printing
document.write('[');
_.each(memo, function (e, idx) {
  document.write("[");
  _.each(e, function(ie, iidx) {
    if (typeof ie === 'string')
      document.write('"' + ie + '"');
    else
      document.write(ie);

    if (iidx != e.length - 1)
        document.write(",");
  });
  document.write("]");
  if (idx != memo.length - 1)
    document.write(",");
});
document.write(']');
```

Output is

```
[["1","7"],["2","8"],["3","9"],[4,"10"],[5,"11"],[6,"12"]]
```

jsbin link -> http://jsbin.com/ajemih/11

I think you got messed input data though as it doesn't comply with output according to types. Unless it is also part of this excercise... :-)

PS. as I understood you wanted literal that's why there's this whole section of document.write but you can ofc skip it if you don't want to print it

mz

Answer (score 2):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XvwkX/1/

I have done it in 2 pass, 1st pass is to construct an easy result which parses the original data object and creates the string literal with the number as key and the 2nd pass is to update the `convertedData` var with the corresponding value.

```
var easyResult = {};
//first pass
$.each(data, function (d, o1) { //date, object1
    $.each (o1, function (t, o2) { //type, object2
        $.each(o2, function (s, n) { //string, ID
            easyResult[n] = t + '-' + s + '-' + d;
        });
    });
});

for (var i = 0; i < convertedData.length; i++ ) {
    for (var j = 0; j < convertedData[i].length; j++) {
        convertedData[i][j] = easyResult[""+convertedData[i][j]];
    }
}
```